# Get salesforce leads data in python

Tags: python-3.x, salesforce

Getting error while i am running this program, Please help me

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
import pandas as pd 
from datetime import datetime
import beatbox 
print("Completed")
```

Error is
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\CompanyWork\PythonPrograms\Programs\Salesforce\SalesforceAPI.py", line 14, in 
import beatbox

Answer (score 0):

Have you correctly install beatbox ?

- Clone the repo in your local machine using `git clone https://github.com/superfell/Beatbox.git`
- Change to the Beatbox directory
- Install the module using `python setup.py install`

Comment: Yes installed Beatbox.